# Bumping max_fds for erlang vm

Tags: erlang, emq

I have an `emqtt` instance installed on `gcloud`. I have to modify the maximum number of file descriptors for `erlang` vm. I have already made all the changes for the host VM but can't seem to figure out how I would change `max_fds` for the `emqtt` vm. There is no argument in `/etc/emqttd/emq.conf` that I can tweak.

The command `emqtt_ctl vm io` gives me the output below:

```
$ emqttd_ctl vm io
io/max_fds              : 1024
io/active_fds           : 0
```

I want to change `io/max_fds` here.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change `max_fds` in Erlang. Maximum of opened file descriptors is usually set by `ulimit -n` from the shell (parent process).

Comment: However, see the -Q option (maximum number of ports) in http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html

Comment: @RichardC: Number of ports and number of file descriptors are two different things.

Comment: Yes, but you may need bumping both.